# httpRuntime shutdownTimeout and the IIS setting

Tags: asp.net, iis

I met an issue in ASP.Net. In any Web App config Web.config file there is a section called httpRuntime, and it has an attriube: shutdownTimeout. According to MSDN documentation, this attr specify how long the idle time of the worker process is allowed before ASP.Net runtime to terminate the worker process. On another side, under IIS's ApplicationPool's -> Default AppPool -> properties -> performance tab, there is a setting: "shutdown worker process after being idle for (20) minutes".

I guess that under IIS, this setting is for all worker process which is used to handle incoming request not only the process where a specific ASP.Net runtime resides. And if Web.Config's shutdownTimeout has not taken effect yet, the IIS's setting would then do its work.

However from my observation, although the httpRuntime's shutdownTimeout default value is 90 seconds, my web application was always shut down after idle for 20 minutes. It seems the IIS setting take priority for this aspect.

It is much appreciated if somebody could clarify on this: what is wrong with my guess.

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging and found out the answer:

the attriubte shutdownTimeout controls how long the ASP.Net runtime will shut down the worker process before it gracefully exits by itself if it is asked to terminate by the ASP.Net runtime.

Is this right, any opinion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Specifies the number of minutes that are allowed for the worker process to shut down. When the time-out expires, ASP.NET shuts down the worker process.

The default is 90.

So basically, the worker process has X minutes to shut down the worker process.  If it reaches X it is killed.