# Run time compile of Razor Templates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor

I have a DNN 9.2 website that I try to keep responsive to new visitors by using a KeepAlive.aspx web page.  This helps when it has not been accessed in a while.  My problem is I'm using a third party module that uses Razor Templates that takes 10-15 seconds to compile the first time a visitors goes to the page.  It is blazing fast after that. I've written a small vb.net application that I keep running to try an hit the pages that have the Razor Templates.

```
        Dim url As String = "Module Page address"
        Dim wReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim oWebResponse As Net.WebResponse
        oWebResponse = wReq.GetResponse()


        Dim respStream As Stream = oWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8)

        oWebResponse.Dispose()
        respStream.Dispose()
        reader.Dispose()
```

I loop this every 60 seconds.  It "seems" to help.  Is this a good way to keep it active?  I have NO control over the code for the module.  End users get very irritated in this day and age of instant response when they have to wait 10+seconds for a simple page to load. Is there a better way?

Comment: have you considered showing a spinner?

Comment: Only the first user will notice the delay and if you do not redeploy the site, it will not happen again. This should not be an issue. When you deploy the site, simply be the first user to access it. Then it will all be fine. You do not need your vb.net application to be hitting it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have any control over the code for a spinner.  It seems that it is the first user after every time the IIS releases the cache.  Coding Yoshi are you saying that the keepalive.aspx page should be enough, so that the site stays active?  That way I would only need to access the page one time?  I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Do you have access to the host? Increase the app pool shutdown time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063653/httpruntime-shutdowntimeout-and-the-iis-setting

Comment: Externally hosted with HostBuddy and another one with TMDHosting so I don't have any control over the app pool.